# Track Mouse Movement using DTW algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-series

I try to implement mouse movement tracking.

To track if the mouse move in circle way Using DTW (Dynamic Time Warping) algorithm, I work with mouse position X,Y to track the movement.

How I can detect if this movement as circle using DTW algorithm.

Code for finding mouse position -

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern long SetCursorPos(int x, int y);
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
```

How I can make that, Can any one help give me link or piece of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice to take a ready to use component which is also availabe as a NuGet package:

https://github.com/gmamaladze/globalmousekeyhook

This library allows you to tap keyboard and mouse, to detect and record their activity even when an application is inactive and runs in background.

On the page you will find also code samples. If you have questions or difficulties just post a Stackowerfow question and tag it with [mousekeyhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mousekeyhook)

This will track your movements. And record a shape.

#### Now you need to detect if your shape is a circle:

For that purpose you can use this library:

http://www.aforgenet.com/aforge/articles/shape_checker/

P.S. I am the author of the component.